# Differences in memory consumption between two identical D7 sites?

Tags: cache, nginx, memory

I'm running Drupal on a news site that has a lot of different View blocks on the front page (~5 total, all cached). In trying to reduce the memory footprint of the site, I've checked out source from SVN to a local development install to try and convert some of those blocks into more optimized code.

Here's the weird thing. Devel module lists memory consumption at 50mb on the Production site (Running Nginx, PHP 5.2.17, XCache and Zend Optimizer.) but only 14mb on my development site (Running Apache2, PHP 5.2.13 and XCache). These are nearly-identical versions of the same site — frankly, the Production site should use even less memory as I've disabled some of the modules running on the Dev site.

Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Probably also worth noting that I had the same issue when migrating the site from one webhost to another — the site was running at 35-40mb on the first webhost and that bounced up to the present consumption of ~50mb on the current webhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really sounds like the difference is between the LAMP stacks and not the site itself.  I suspect that your production server has more PHP options installed/enabled.

Comment: The PHP module loads seem pretty similar. I agree it's probably the LAMP stack and not a code-related thing. Think the fact the production webspace runs FastCGI has anything to do with it?

Comment: Not really sure.  You may want to flag and ask that this be moved to ServerFault.  You may get better answers there.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking ServerFault might've been a better place to ask shortly after I posted the question. Will do that. Thanks!